# Standard project/package structure of a j2ee web application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

We are starting a new Java EE web application using Spring, Sping MVC and Hibernate. We will most probably be using maven also.

Before starting we need to come up with the project/package structure for the web application.

What is the Standard project/package structure of a Java EE web application?

It should also run on all application servers without making any changes in the project structure or the any configuration files.

We will be using Spring source IDE version 2.6.0 (latest release).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you are using maven, it's best to follow the standard maven project layout.  You can get maven to generate this structure for you by doing,

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

and select spring-mvc-jpa-archetype from the list of choices

This will give you a package structure like,

```
  ├── pom.xml
  └── src
      ├── main
      │   ├── java
      │   │   └── mygroup
      │   │       ├── controller
      │   │       │   ├── HomeController.java
      │   │       │   └── PersonController.java
      │   │       ├── dao
      │   │       │   └── PersonDao.java
      │   │       └── model
      │   │           └── Person.java
      │   ├── resources
      │   │   ├── db.properties
      │   │   ├── log4j.xml
      │   │   └── META-INF
      │   │       └── persistence.xml
      │   └── webapp
      │       ├── index.html
      │       ├── META-INF
      │       │   ├── context.xml
      │       │   └── MANIFEST.MF
      │       ├── resources
      │       │   └── css
      │       │       └── screen.css
      │       └── WEB-INF
      │           ├── spring
      │           │   ├── app
      │           │   │   ├── controllers.xml
      │           │   │   └── servlet-context.xml
      │           │   ├── db.xml
      │           │   └── root-context.xml
      │           ├── views
      │           │   ├── edit.jsp
      │           │   ├── home.jsp
      │           │   └── list.jsp
      │           └── web.xml
      └── test
          ├── java
          │   └── mygroup
          │       ├── controller
          │       │   ├── DataInitializer.java
          │       │   ├── HomeControllerTest.java
          │       │   └── PersonControllerTest.java
          │       └── dao
          │           └── PersonDaoTest.java
          └── resources
              ├── db.properties
              ├── log4j.xml
              ├── test-context.xml
              └── test-db.xml
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I tried that but we wont be using ejb's etc stuff. In addition to this, how do i structure my classes i.e. spring controllers, models, daos, services, business logic, various interfaces etc ?

Answer (score 24):

A common, more complete Java package structure for a MVCSR (Model, View, Controller, Service, Repository) web application goes something like:

```
java
└── com
    └── youdomain
        |
        ├── base   // broadly used app-wide base and abstract classes)
        |
        ├── core   // broadly, scattered use helpers, utilities, app health/stats
        |          // tracking, logging, etc
        |
        ├── controller // Fields Http/CGI requests and drives/initiates request 
        |          // comprehension, validation, security checks, requesting 
        |          // operations by the Service module and invoking the View to 
        |          // generate a response.
        |
        ├── data   // This is the lower level data infrastructure, with several
        |          //packages under it for mappers, schema tables/enums, helpers,
        |          // record location, id management, etc
        |
        ├── domain // app-wide exposed classes, managers, and interfaces to
        |          // each persisted (usually DB) domain 'object'. Each
        |          // object often correlates to one table row in you DB.
        |          // Domain objects are mostly considered data, but have some fundamental
        |          // record construction, validation, elaboration, and ancillary information
        |          // functionality which is opaque to the rest of the application. 
        |          // For example: Customer, Account, Purchase, Inventory, 
        |          // Product, Sale, Return, SpecialOffer, FeedbackComment...
        |
        ├── repository // more complicated persisted objects, often structured
        |       // to address certain efficiency or traversal needs, often each
        |       // repository is underpinned by several records, tables, 
        |       // and even cross-DB structures. Example: 
        |       //  -- OrderHistory, 
        |       //  -- ProductsGlobalSearchIndex, 
        |       //  -- CustomerSpecificProductMarketingSuggestionCorrelates
        |
        ├── service // The smarts of the whole application, performs macro, holoistic 
        |       //  operations involving multiple DB tables and operations. Such as:
        |       //  -- account.UserAccountLifecycle, 
        |       //  -- order.CustomerOrder, 
        |       //  -- order.CustomerOrderShipment
        |
        └── view // Intefaces with your jsp, freemarker, tapestry etc.
```