# Java web app recommended project structure

Tags: java, web, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm using IntelliJ to create one of my first web apps. I'd like to use Gradle to solve my dependencies. Depending on how I create the project, it is structured differently.

I was wondering whether there is a recommended project structure for web apps. Where to put the static pages? Where to put the classes? Where the other resources (like images)? And where to put other framework-specific files, like the build.gradle file?

Right now I see three alternatives:

If I create the project as a Java web application (File -> New Project -> check Java::JavaEE::Web Application -> Next etc...) I get the following project structure:

```
|-- WebApp.iml
|-- src
`-- web
    |-- WEB-INF
    |   `-- web.xml
    `-- index.jsp
```

If I create a Gradle project (File -> New Project -> check Gradle::Java and Gradle::Web -> Next etc...) I get the following structure:

```
|-- build
|   `-- tmp
|       `-- war
|           `-- MANIFEST.MF
|-- build.gradle
|-- GradleWebApp.iml
|-- out
|-- settings.gradle
`-- src
    `-- main
        `-- webapp
            `-- index.jsp
```

Before using IntelliJ I manually deployed a basic application to my local tomcat. The project structure was the following:

```
|-- WEB-INF
|   |-- classes
|   |   `-- servletsPkg
|   |       `-- AServlet.class
|   |-- src
|   |   `-- servletsPkg
|   |       `-- AServlet.java
|   `-- web.xml
|-- images
|   `-- an_image.jpg
|-- index.html
`-- styles.css
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with gradle, but it's wrong to deploy the sources (AServlet.java) in WEB-INF/src... , as you show in the third structure. Such a folder must not exist in a servlet  container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also found these two related stackExchange questions:

- [Java web application folder structure](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/222732/java-web-application-folder-structure)
- [Standard project/package
  structure of a j2ee web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878774/standard-project-package-structure-of-a-j2ee-web-application#5878903)

Not combined with gradle though...

However, finally came up with this project structure:

```
|-- Reference.iml
|-- gradle.build
|-- src
|   |-- java
|   |   `-- servlets
|   |       `-- AServlet.java
|   `-- test
|       `-- java
`-- web
    |-- WEB-INF
    |   `-- web.xml
    |-- resources
    |   `-- AnImage.jpg
    `-- index.html
```

Resembles most to the Java Web App initial structure.
Went for this because it seemed to separate better the static part of the application from the java classes. I like thinking that the classes are the (only?) real "src" of the project.

Please let me know if there is anything that seems wrong with it.